# Round ends of group of cylinders - Solidworks 2015

Tags: solidworks

I'm trying to completely round the ends of all 3 of the attached merged cylinder-shaped detail.

I've tried using a fillet, but it fails beyond the first arc. And it also won't allow a fillet the same radius as the cylinders.

[image]

Comment: better ask this at http://forum.solidworks.com

Answer (score 0):

Draw 3 circles on top in different features and extrude them a very small amount (.0001, .0002, .0003) then use the dome feature, you may have to do it in the correct order.
Once you have the 3 domes, you can fillet the gaps in the middle of that is what you want?